# QTP- add obj to local - object locations are not aligned - 1' away from its image

Tags: qtp

( I used chasestudentloans.com from tutorial if anyone needs reference to where i'm stuck)
I copy/ pasted a line to add a WebEdit object, run, get error that obj not found in OR.
I try to add obj to local, I click on top of the WebEdit area in the app, but it seems out of alignment with image:  I had to guess-click about 1 inch higher on the app window to find the correcponding element.  If I clicked on exact location as per image, I got a WebEdit element that was 2 lines below... 
What is strange to me is previously I had no problem with this step. I haven't done any software updates since then.

Anyone knows why this is out of alignment? Something with the monitor or software?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It might happen sometimes if you're using zoom different from 100%.